# Firebase Crash Report Hidden

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I am using Firebase for my crash reports, I have a run script in Xcode that uploads my dsym files.

Today I have a crash report in firebase but the stack trace has these lines that just say hidden where you would expect to see lines from your code that caused the crash.

How do I get rid of these "hidden" lines and show the real lines of code?
below is what firebase crash report looks like for me.

```
1 MyAppName __hidden#483_ (__hidden#9327_:64)
2 MyAppName __hidden#483_ (__hidden#9327_:64)
3 MyAppName __hidden#483_ (__hidden#9327_)
4 Foundation _decodeObjectBinary + 418924
5 Foundation -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 446284
6 etc....
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is there an update to this question? Because I am facing the same problem right now even though all my dSYM files are uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by disabling bitcode.
In the Build Settings set "Enable Bitcode" to No.

[image]

Also make sure you are not missing dSYM files in the firebase console, there is a dSYM tab near Dashboard.
[image]